# Does the platform matter when making a UIViewController Subclass without a XIB?

Tags: ios, xcode4

Using XCode 4, I used the template to generate a UIViewController subclass. However, I do not need a XIB.

Does the "Targeted for iPad" option do anything else besides change the generated XIB in this template? I cannot seem to find any changes, I am just curious to find out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is no, as confirmed by my own tests.